# Dimensional Model Design

Tags: sql-server, dimensional-modeling

I am use to Snowflake ER Model, decided to delve into Star Schema Dimensional Model (Facts & Dimension).

**Background**
Hospital Data: Track Patient what issues (Comorbidities) a patient had prior a surgical procedure i.e Heart condition

**Issue**
A Patient can have many Procedures, each procedure can have many issues (Patient is asked before every Procedure if they have any issues (Comorbidities) i.e. heart)

**Design**

- Procedure Fact table, track how many procedures they had, Date of
  procedure, their age at time the procedure, patient id …
- Comorbidities Bridge Table, to manage the 1 to many relationship
  between a Procedure and Comorbidity , this is used to populate the
  Comorbidities Fact Table (Each procedure can record more than 1 issue
  , i.e. Patient has heart condition, has blood condition ..)
- Comorbidities Fact Table, Tracks each Comorbidity (Patient issue) for
  each Procedure

I want to **Calculate the % of Comorbidities for each Procedure**

**Is there a more efficient way of doing it**, than what I am doing? I feel I am finding myself going down the rabbit hole and getting caught in a Snowflake ER Model design on top of a Star Schema

**Calculation**

```
With CTE As 
             (
               --PROCEDURES
              Select  
               [ProcedureSite] ,
               [ProcedureType], 
               SUM([NumOfProcedures])As[NumOfProcedures]
              From [Fact].[Procedures]P
               Inner Join [Dim].[Procedure]P1 On P1.[ProcedureID]= p.[ProcedureID]
              Group By 
               [ProcedureSite],
               [ProcedureType]

             )




--COMORBIT
     Select 
      P1.[ProcedureSite], 
         P1.[ProcedureType],
      [Comorbidity],
      Sum([NumOfComorbidities]) As [NumOfComorbidities],
      C2.[NumOfProcedures]
      From [Fact].[Comorbidity]C1
      Inner Join [Dim].[Procedure]P1 On P1.[ProcedureID]= C1.[ProcedureID]
      Inner Join [Dim].[Comorbidity]C On C1.[ComorbidityID] = C.[ComorbidityID]
      Left Join CTE C2 On P1.[ProcedureSite] = C2.[ProcedureSite] And P1.[ProcedureType] =C2.[ProcedureType]
      Group By P1.[ProcedureSite], 
      P1.[ProcedureType],[Comorbidity],[NumOfProcedures]
      Order By 
      P1.[ProcedureSite], 
      P1.[ProcedureType]
```

**DB Setup**

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ao-FTTt3GMhriI1nLvNAEJRowR1jTQ?e=EunmNa

Comment: Can you please use https://dbfiddle.uk/ for create the DB setup?

Comment: Thanks , was not aware of that tool , that script is updated , works in dbfiddle https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ao-FTTt3GMhriI1nLvNAEJRowR1jTQ?e=EunmNa